# Visual Studio 2022: Could not load type 'System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0

Tags: c#

How to fix this error in Visual Studio 2022:

Error       Unknown build error, 'Could not load type 'System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'  Garbo

[image: markdig]

Heres the markdig.dll project that is causing the error in my projct above by reference to this dll.  (https://github.com/xoofx/markdig)

[image]

[image]

```
PSChildName                      Version
-----------                      -------
v2.0.50727                       2.0.50727.4927
v3.0                             3.0.30729.4926
Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.4926
Windows Presentation Foundation  3.0.6920.4902
v3.5                             3.5.30729.4926
Client                           4.8.04161
Full                             4.8.04161
Client                           4.0.0.0
```

Comment: what flavor of .net/wpf are you using?

Comment: Have you done anything significant recently that may have caused this error to start appearing?

Comment: I'm just using the default .net flavor that comes with visual studio 2022... However, the DLL i'm including, "markdig.dll", makes use of .Net 6 and .Net 4.52

Comment: Have you got any version of .Net Framework installed like 4.8?

Comment: how to check?  i think i have .net 6 and .net 4.52 installed...

Comment: Can you run the following as admin (in Powershell) and post output of `Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version`

Comment: What is your project's Framework target ? I have a feeling that you might have referenced a version of the markdig assembly that does not target a compatible framework. Actually why not just reference markdig as a nuget package ? Less chances for anything to go awry.

Comment: @phuzi in the second screenshot yeah, in the first it's OPs solution and we can't see if he referenced the assembly directly or the markdig project. If he referenced the project VS should have selected the correct version for him, if not it's possible he might not have the good one referenced

Comment: How to check framework target in visual studio?

Comment: @pico Right click on your project then properties, should appear in "target framework". Or optionally open the .csproj with a text editor and look for the xml tag `TargetFramework`

Comment: I'd really recommend trying to install markdig as a nuget package first though unless you have a really specific reason as to why you shouldn't (right click on dependencies => manage nuget packages => install => search markdig select it and install)

Comment: nuget works to fix it:  "Package Manager Console", "PM> Install-Package Markdig -Version 0.30.2"

Comment: I wonder what's happening there, [`system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute?view=net-6.0) is NOT supposed to be in System.Runtime....

Comment: @pico ok, so you either had referenced a wrong version of the assembly or missed having in your output folder some of the dependencies for markdig (which is kinda one of the reasons to use nuget, it makes sure dependencies are satisfied)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deleted the "obj" folder inside the project folder and then clean and rebuild the project. This works for me.